# How can I convert a Gauss-Markov process to i.i.d. Gaussian process?

Tags: autoregressive

I am wondering is there any straight forward approach to convert a Gauss-Markov process, i.e., a First order autoregressive process with i.i.d. Gaussian input, with the covariance matrix $K=Toeplitz(1, \rho, \rho^2, \ldots, \rho^{N-1})$ where $0 \leq \rho < 1$ is the normalized correlation coefficient, to i.i.d. Gaussian process.

As I know, I can apply eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition (KLT) to make the process uncorrelated and independent (since the process is jointly Gaussian), but the converted process is not identically distributed due to the variety of variances (eigenvalues).

Thanks a lot in advance,
Farzad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an $AR(1)$ process:

$$y_t=\rho y_{t-1}+u_t$$

with $u_t$ normal, then $y_t$ are normal too with covariance matrix $\Omega=K/(1-\rho^2)$, not $K$. To transform them to iid you can use [Prais-Winsten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prais%E2%80%93Winsten_estimation) transformation matrix $G$, which satisfies $G'G=\Omega^{-1}$.